# State is getting reset when changing route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-router-dom

I have a `Navbar` component in my react app. I manage the admin state within the `Navbar` component. When I'm already on the `Lag` route and tries to route to `Medlemar` the admin part of the navbar disappears. This is because the admin state is getting reset when changing route. How can I prevent this?

Navbar component:

```
function Navbar({ data }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false)
  const [passedData, setData] = useState(undefined)

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setUser(user)
    })

    if (passedData) {
      console.log(passedData)
    } else {
      setData(data)
    }

    if (user) {
      if(passedData !== undefined) {
        firebase.firestore().collection('teams').doc(passedData.teamID).collection('members').doc(user.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
          const administrator = snapshot.get('role')

          if (administrator === 'admin') {
            setAdmin(true)
          } else {
            setAdmin(false)
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }, [user])

    return (
        <nav className='navbar'>
          <ul className='nav-menu-items'>
            <li className="nav-text">
              <Link to="/">
                <AiIcons.AiFillDashboard size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                <span>Dashboard</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-text">
              <Link to="/lag">
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineTeam size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                <span>Lag</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-text">
              <Link to="/profil">
                <BsIcons.BsPerson size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                <span>Profil</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-text">
              <Link to="/betaling">
                <GiIcons.GiPayMoney size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                <span>Betaling</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            </ul>
            {admin ? 
              <>
              <span className="admin-text">Admin</span>
              <div className="navbar-divider"></div>
                <ul className="nav-menu-items">
                  <li className="nav-text">
                    <Link to={{
                      pathname: `/lag/${data.teamID}/admin/medlemar`,
                      state: {
                        passedData: data,
                      }
                    }}>
                      <BsIcons.BsPeopleFill className="icon" size="1.4em" />
                      <span>Medlemar</span>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                </>
            :
              null
            }
        </nav>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/logg-inn" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/lag/:id" exact component={Team} />
          <Route path="/profil" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/registrer-deg" component={Signup} />
          <Route path="/lag" exact component={Teams} />
          <Route path="/lag/:id/innstillingar" exact component={TeamSettings} />
          <Route path="/lag/:id/betaling" exact component={Payment} />
          <Route path="/lag/:id/arrangement" exact component={Events} />
          <Route path="/lag/:id/admin/medlemar" component={Members} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where are you using Navbar component ?

Comment: In every page component

Comment: You should use the NavBar component in a common place. maybe in your App file. just before the routes

Comment: Oh wait, sorry. I don't use it in the Login component, and not in the Signup component. So not every component

Comment: You could also lift the state up and define admin, setAdmin on App.js and pass them down as props. But it would be probably better to use the NavBar only in App.js

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist state inbetween the routes with your Navbar then you should use it as a wrapper component and wrap /lag routes with this.

Generaly it would be better to use React Context or any other state managing library to avoid future problems, but the solution I provided should be working.

Your Navbar component could take children(for wrapping purposes) and look like this per say:

```
function Navbar({ data, children }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(false);
    const [passedData, setData] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setUser(user);
        });

        if (passedData) {
            console.log(passedData);
        } else {
            setData(data);
        }

        if (user) {
            if (passedData !== undefined) {
                firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('teams')
                    .doc(passedData.teamID)
                    .collection('members')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) => {
                        const administrator = snapshot.get('role');

                        if (administrator === 'admin') {
                            setAdmin(true);
                        } else {
                            setAdmin(false);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }, [user]);

    return (
        <nav className="navbar">
            <ul className="nav-menu-items">
                <li className="nav-text">
                    <Link to="/">
                        <AiIcons.AiFillDashboard
                            size="1.4em"
                            className="icon"
                        />
                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-text">
                    <Link to="/lag">
                        <AiIcons.AiOutlineTeam size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                        <span>Lag</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-text">
                    <Link to="/profil">
                        <BsIcons.BsPerson size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                        <span>Profil</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-text">
                    <Link to="/betaling">
                        <GiIcons.GiPayMoney size="1.4em" className="icon" />
                        <span>Betaling</span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {admin ? (
                <>
                    <span className="admin-text">Admin</span>
                    <div className="navbar-divider"></div>
                    <ul className="nav-menu-items">
                        <li className="nav-text">
                            <Link
                                to={{
                                    pathname: `/lag/${data.teamID}/admin/medlemar`,
                                    state: {
                                        passedData: data,
                                    },
                                }}
                            >
                                <BsIcons.BsPeopleFill
                                    className="icon"
                                    size="1.4em"
                                />
                                <span>Medlemar</span>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </>
            ) : null}

            {children}
        </nav>
    );
}
```

and then your App would be looking something like this:

```
function App() {
    return (
      <>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/logg-inn" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/lag/:id" exact component={Team} />
            <Route path="/profil" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/registrer-deg" component={Signup} />
            <Navbar>
            <Route path="/lag" exact component={Teams} />
            <Route path="/lag/:id/innstillingar" exact component={TeamSettings} />
            <Route path="/lag/:id/betaling" exact component={Payment} />
            <Route path="/lag/:id/arrangement" exact component={Events} />
            <Route path="/lag/:id/admin/medlemar" component={Members} />
            </Navbar>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand you, could you please explain a bit more. Sorry, I'm still very new to React.

Comment: I will edit my answer with code example in a second

Comment: Thanks, I understood it now. I'll take a look on it later

Comment: sure, if this answer your question please dont forget to mark it as a answer and upvote aswell

Comment: Now, I get two navbars below each other and for example the Members page inside the Navbar.